# How do I get time diiference between two dates in milliseconds in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In Javascript I can use `var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();` to get the time in milliseconds. Is there any similar method in C#?

Answer (score 5):

Subtracting a `DateTime` from another `DateTime` returns a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
TimeSpan ts = d2 - d1;
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalMilliseconds);
// Outputs 86400000
```